# 1x1 size Nine-patch image not showing up on Android emulator device

Tags: android

I'd like to use a 1x1 size Nine-patch image from Android drawable resources.
When I'm trying to display it with `<ImageView>` in my layout xml file, this one is never showing up on the Android emulator device. Here's the xml code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10px"
>
<RelativeLayout 
 android:gravity="center_vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <TextView android:id="@+id/text_label"
     android:text="@string/text"
     android:textSize="10pt"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 <CheckBox android:id="@+id/my_checkBox"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/text_label"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView android:paddingTop="10px"
        android:paddingBottom="10px"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried another one with the same size and I have the same problem it's still blank.

My research on Google was irrelevant. Hope you can find what am I doing wrong here.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Lorenth

Comment: how about if you set it as background? android:background="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright". Also another test, do you see the line if you set a color like "#ff0000" ?

Comment: Does the 9 patch image still have the 1px border around it to set the expandable area?

Comment: @Mathias Lin. Thanks for answering me back. Nope it's still blank by changing "src" to "background". Otherwise it works well by setting the background with a predefined color. It's weird actually because it works well now with "divider_horizontal_dark" but not with "divider_horizontal_bright"o_O while it's the same size. Totally not understand why?

Comment: @roundhill. I think so. The 9 patch image comes from android drawable resources so I suppose they did not omit it.

Comment: android:layout_height="1px" ?

Comment: @roundhill. Sorry I was misunderstanding your question. I already changed the "layout_height" to 1px in the xml code but that is not the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of the SDK are you writing for?
Take a peek at the divider_horizontal_bright.png files in the different versions :) 
It's 99% transparent in 8, but like 50% transparent light grey in 4.

Or, Perhaps you meant divider_horizontal_bright_opaque?

Comment: Thanks for answering me back. I'm using the 7 one and it’s certainly about the transparency but I think there’s a little confusion between "bright" and "dark" terms. For me, it was logical using a bright divider on a dark background but it's not. So for those who don't know that use "divider_horizontal_dark" instead of "divider_horizontal_bright" on a dark background and vice versa. Thanks everyone for your help;)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark"
  android:scaleType="fitXY"
/>
```